# Copy data from excel to excel with openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Couldn't find answers I can understand. So I've decided to ask.
I'm learning Python. And now I'm trying to solve a problem with collecting data from active spreadsheet in one excel file and paste it to another excel file. The first file contains table and a few cells with information to the right of it. I'm trying to fully copy the spreadsheet data.

```
import openpyxl, os
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

os.chdir('D:\\Python')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('auto.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Create new workbook and chose active worksheet.
wbNew = openpyxl.Workbook()
wsNew = wbNew.active

# Loop through all cells (rows, then columns) in the first file
# and fill in the second one.
for allObj in ws['A1':get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)]:
    for cellObj in allObj:
        for allNewObj in wsNew:
            for newCellObj in allNewObj:
               wsNew[cellObj.coordinate].value = cellObj.value
wbNew.save('example.xlsx')
```

Finally it works.

Comment: `wbNew = openpyxl.Workbook('example.xlsx')` is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Changed it to `wbNew = openpyxl.Workbook()`

Comment: Added `wsNew[cellObj.coordinate].value = cellObj.value` and it worked.

Comment: Your for loop can be simplified to `for row in ws:. You should remove the recursive loop `for allNewObj in wsNew` as this will get slower and slower as the worksheet grows.

Comment: It works great and much faster with your advice. Thank you!